# Location ignored in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I've a simple location in my nginx config but never catched

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location /healthcheck {
        access_log off;
        add_header Content-Type "text/plain";
        return 200 "OK\n";
    }

    return 301 http://www.google.fr;
}
```

Everytime I go to http://xxx/healthcheck the location is not detected and I'm redirected to Google.

What did I do wrong in my file?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please switch 301 to 302 redirect code and use anon mode in browser, or better use curl to check healthcheck url.
For example:

`curl -IL http://xxx/healthcheck`

301 is always a problem when you are testing something.

Change won't be imidiate. Please be patient. Let us know

Comment: To expand on the answer, 301 is a _permanent_ redirect, which browsers will cache pretty much forever, whereas 302 redirects just for the one request.

Answer (score 0):

The `=` prefix means that the location specified should exactly match the requested URL.

Here is the working setting

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location = /healthcheck {
        access_log off;
        add_header Content-Type "text/plain";
        return 200 "OK\n";
    }

    return 301 http://www.google.fr;
}
```

**OR**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location /healthcheck {
        access_log off;
        add_header Content-Type "text/plain";
        return 200 "OK\n";
    }
}
```

**Note**: Don't forget to reload nginx after all the changes `sudo nginx -s reload`

Comment: Can you please try other approach which I posted in my answer. @Sylvain

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and figured it out! nginx's `return` doesn't return like in PHP (or other programming languages), it continues to read the file. So, your return is being overwritten with the next one. Instead, you need to add your other return in another location {}

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name _;

   location = /healthcheck {
      access_log off;
      add_header Content-Type "text/plain";
      return 200 "OK\n";
   }

   location / {
      return 301 http://www.google.fr;
   }
}
```